# How to change page language in C# of GeckoFx component

Tags: c#, locale, geckofx

I'm using GeckFx component in C#, but I need to change the page language (locale) manually? Because, automatically, it view pages in English (instead I need to see them in Italian).

The version of GeckoFX v.60.0.26.0.

```
Public NewPrint(Main main)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
   this.main = main;
}
```

And in the Load method I navigate in the web site, via:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://example_page.com");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please add details/code regarding your question

Comment: I've just inizialised it.
So, my code is:

public NewPrint(Main main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            this.main = main;
        }

And in the Load method I navigate in the web site, via:

geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://example_page.com");

Comment: Sounds like [How to override headers in geckoFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739406/how-to-override-headers-in-geckofx). Have you tried: `GeckoPreferences.User["intl.accept_languages"] = "it";`

Comment: Yes!That's the solution. Thank you very much.